# Ordinary differential equation using Laplace Transform method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> $$xy'' + (2x + 3)y' + (x + 3)y = 3e^{–x} \\ y(0) = 0
> $$

I know I can plug in $L[y''],L[y']$ and get a first order linear differential equation, but I just cannot get the right answer.

I use the universal equation to solve the first order equation, is there anything wrong with my steps? Grateful for any answer!!!
[image]

Comment: Check your signs on the exponentials in line 2. You've done something wrong there.

Comment: If you just want to solve the equation, propose the solution $y = P(x)e^{-x}$ where $P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ and substitute in the differential equation and solve for $a,b,c$.

Comment: Please use images only to document the original form of the task, if there is something in doubt with it, or for illustrations. Text and formulas should be given as text and mathjax. Change your notation to something simpler if necessary, for instance $L[y]$ to $Y(p)$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer and helpful reminder. It is my first time to enter this forum so I don't really know some requests. I will take care next time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Not using Laplace, one can factorize the equation as the sum of the outer coefficients is the inner coefficient
$$
x(D^2+D)+(x+3)(D+1)=(xD+x+3)(D+1)\\
=(x(D+1)+3)(D+1)=(D+1)(x(D+1)+2)
$$
This allows to solve the second order equation as a sequence of two first-order equations
$$
z'+z=3e^{-x},\\
xy'+(x+2)y=z.
$$
Other such decompositions are possible.

---

The DE is regular singular at $x=0$, so that the implied boundedness there is a second boundary condition. There might be strange effects on the Laplace transform.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get this method but this question is from my homework. So I think maybe I should work it out by plugging in L[y'] and L[y"]

Comment: Yes of course. This is to have an alternative to check your solution. And you can find similarities to the Laplace approach. That only works so well as it does because of the factorization. Modify the coefficients slightly and the factorization will no longer exist and the Laplace transformed equation will also have no easy solution.